Expo go show nothing but web show eveything [React Native]
I have a project named "Wikuhotel" use Expo React Native, if i open it on web the "Cart.tsx" screen show perfectly but when i open it on phone it show nothing
I tried to log the Local parameters I used to take data from Menu and it work perfectly

it should look like this(open that on web)

but when I open it on mobile app using expo go, it won't show nothing.
this is my Cart.tsx
const Cart = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const localParams = useLocalSearchParams<{
    menus: string;
    itemPrices: string;
    total: string;
  }>();
  console.log(localParams);
  const [menus] = useState(localParams.menus.split(", "));
  const [prices] = useState(
    localParams.itemPrices.split(", ").map((price) => Number(price))
  );
  const [total] = useState(Number(localParams.total));

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <CartComp itemPrices={prices} menus={menus} total={total} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

and this is my CartComp.tsx
const CartComp = ({
  menus,
  itemPrices,
  total,
}: {
  menus: string[];
  itemPrices: number[];
  total: number;
}) => {
  const data = menus.map((menu, index) => ({
    menu,
    price: itemPrices[index],
  }));

  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Order list</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.menu}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.priceText}>${item.price.toFixed(2)}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />

      <View style={styles.totalContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.totalText}>Total: ${total.toFixed(2)}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

I think there is nothing wrong with my code but why is this happened?

You should add flex:1 to SafeAreaView on Cart function component to fill in space

well it work, tysm sir
